# Persist info in form contained within Bootstrap Popover

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, popover

I have a form within a Bootstrap popover. The form shows and works fine; however, when I close the popup and then re-open it, all of my input data is lost. Is there a way to persist the input data and have it show when re-opening?

I've already tried copying it with jQuery's `html()` function and assigning it to the "`data-original-title`" attribute yet it doesn't copy the form values.

Has anyone worked out a solution?